# Как декодировать русский текст?

Tags: python, кодировка, unicode, yaml

При выполнении кода, получаю YAML-файл:

```
"\u0422\u0443\u043B\u044C\u0441\u043A\u0438\u0439":
  DustEpic: 0
  DustLegendary: 0
  DustRare: 0
  EssenceEpic: 0
  EssenceLegendary: 0
  EssenceRare: 0
  Ruby: 2
  RunestoneEpic: 0
  RunestoneLegendary: 0
  RunestoneRare: 0
  _GENERAL: 2
  _TIMES: 1
```

Как выводить текст (`"\u0422\u0443\u043B\u044C\u0441\u043A\u0438\u0439"`) на русском вместо Unicode?

Comment: А в сам питон в каком виде эта строка попадает? Так то она уже на русском на самом деле: `print("\u0422\u0443\u043B\u044C\u0441\u043A\u0438\u0439")` -> `Тульский`

Comment: А как вписывать нормальный текст? Русский. Просто при проверки, на наличие пользователя в файле, каждый раз создаётся новая структура: https://i.imgur.com/kFhO6aq.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В дополнение к ответу @CrazyElf хотел бы напомнить, что в YAML можно записывать юникодные строки - тогда и при чтении сразу получим нормальный юникодный текст:

```
from yaml import safe_load, dump

data = {'Тульский': {'DustEpic': 0, 'DustLegendary': 0, 'DustRare': 0, 'EssenceEpic': 0, 'EssenceLegendary': 0, 'EssenceRare': 0, 'Ruby': 2, 'RunestoneEpic': 0, 'RunestoneLegendary': 0, 'RunestoneRare': 0, '_GENERAL': 2, '_TIMES': 1}}

with open("test.yaml", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    dump(data, file, allow_unicode=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Даже если у вас файл прямо в таком виде, питон его прочитает нормально. Запишем прямо в таком виде в файл:

```
s = r'''"\u0422\u0443\u043B\u044C\u0441\u043A\u0438\u0439":
  DustEpic: 0
  DustLegendary: 0
  DustRare: 0
  EssenceEpic: 0
  EssenceLegendary: 0
  EssenceRare: 0
  Ruby: 2
  RunestoneEpic: 0
  RunestoneLegendary: 0
  RunestoneRare: 0
  _GENERAL: 2
  _TIMES: 1
'''

with open('test.yaml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Проверим содержимое файла:

```
!cat test.yaml

"\u0422\u0443\u043B\u044C\u0441\u043A\u0438\u0439":
  DustEpic: 0
  DustLegendary: 0
  DustRare: 0
  EssenceEpic: 0
  EssenceLegendary: 0
  EssenceRare: 0
  Ruby: 2
  RunestoneEpic: 0
  RunestoneLegendary: 0
  RunestoneRare: 0
  _GENERAL: 2
  _TIMES: 1
```

Всё как у вас. Теперь прочитаем:

```
import yaml

with open("test.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    data_loaded = yaml.safe_load(stream)

print(data_loaded)
```

Вывод:

```
{'Тульский': {'DustEpic': 0, 'DustLegendary': 0, 'DustRare': 0, 'EssenceEpic': 0, 'EssenceLegendary': 0, 'EssenceRare': 0, 'Ruby': 2, 'RunestoneEpic': 0, 'RunestoneLegendary': 0, 'RunestoneRare': 0, '_GENERAL': 2, '_TIMES': 1}}
```